# Entity Framework: add property that don't map to database

Tags: entity-framework, entity

Is it possible to add a property to an entity where the property is not supposed to map to the database?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Possible? Sure; add it to a custom partial class matching your entity type. Useful? Less so; you (mostly) can't use them in LINQ to Entities queries, and you shouldn't re-purpose your entities as view models.

Comment: Adding properties in an partial class works fine when reading from database to display info on screen. But when I'm saving an entity I get an error telling me that the column (the added property) does not exist. How can I avoid thid issue? Any thoughts?

Comment: I can't give a useful answer with only a vague description of the error you're seeing and nothing precise about what you're doing. The source code, the exact error, and a call stack is really a minimum for "debugging over the web."

Answer (score 15):

You need to mark the property in the custom partial class to "[NotMapped]".  Hope this helps.

Comment: given the question - this should be the accepted answer not sure what the above answer is about...