# Have model contain field without adding it to the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

In my Asp.NET MVC4 application I want to add a field to my model without adding it to the database.

Sort of a field that only lives in c# instances of the model but not in the database itself.

Is there any annotation or other way to exclude the field from the database itself?

I mean an object I can read and write in runtime which the database has no knowledge of.

Comment: That's why we have **models** and **viewmodels**. The first represent your business objects and they MUST (most of time) be mapped to a database. The later will simply hold any data that your view requires to work properly.

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework 'Code First'?

Comment: @AndreCalil
I see but I'd prefer to avoid creating an entire view model seeing as I only have one field value I need a setter and getter for.

Comment: @Zebedee Ok, so review this question, please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385248/ignoring-a-class-property-in-entity-framework-4-1-code-first

Comment: @AndreCalil it is not true that a model **must** be mapped to a DB. It is very common to have none DB driven Models.

Comment: @Liam Please, read my comment again. I said *most of times* because, obviously, there may be situations where your model is not tied to your database. Your comment was somewhat useless, to be true.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Just decorate your field/property with `[NotMapped]`.

For example:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute.aspx

Answer (score 2):

That depends what framework you are using to access your data. I assume it's Entity Framework. Well, you can create partial class with the property that you wanty to not be mapped to your database.

something like

```
public class Class1
{
    string Text { get; set; }

    int Number { get; set; }
}

public partial class Class1
{
    bool IsSomething { get; set; }
}
```

but that is not advised. 
More:
[Entity Framework: add property that don't map to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771877/entity-framework-add-property-that-dont-map-to-database)

Or if you're using Code First:
[Ignoring a class property in Entity Framework 4.1 Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385248/ignoring-a-class-property-in-entity-framework-4-1-code-first)